# How to store double with maximum precision

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, types

I'm a bit stucked with storing number with maximum available precision:

```
double tmp = 569.232306826889043804840184748172760009765625L;
```

I'm trying to print it on the screen:

```
printf("%0.52f\n", tmp);
```

And that's what I've got:

> 569.2323068268890400000000000000000000000000000000000000

Is this the maximum precision which I can achieve?

P.S. I'm using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: In C++ you can use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) to find out the limits and precision.

Comment: You should also remember that there is not only precision but als accuracy. A lot of decimal numbers cannot be exactly represented with floating points.

Comment: `I'm a bit stucked with storing number with maximum available precision`   Why stuck?  Just declare a `double` (or `long double`), and there you have your "maximum precision".  Otherwise I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: check out [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats) for some information on floating point numbers

Comment: If you need more precision than that there are high precision libraries floating around on the net.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A double is usually stored in [IEEE 754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) format.

A binary64 has 52 *bits* of precision, not 52 decimal digits - this is equivalent to at most 17 decimal digits, which is what you're displaying.

---

> Is this the maximum precision which I can achieve?

Some platforms *may* provide a `long double` which is actually bigger than a `double`, but yours doesn't seem to.

If you want more precision, you can either use a library that exposes some larger/more precise type supported by your hardware (such as the 80-bit extended double), or an arbitrary-precision library that works in software.

Comment: The language doesn't specify the precision of `double`, though it does specify minimum requirements. 52 bits is typical, but not required.

Comment: To be precise, this answer describes some of the characteristics of the IEEE-754 binary double precision ("binary64") format.  That's the floating-point format relevant to the question, but it should not be taken to imply that C requires implementations to use that format as their representation of type `double`.  That is by far the most common choice, these days, though.

Answer (score 6):

That is the precision of type `double` in your C implementation.  Conformant C implementations also have a type `long double`, which *may* offer greater precision.

If you need more precision than that then there are numeric libraries that provide arbitrary-precision numeric types and functions to operate on them.  The [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/) is one such; it works on many platforms, including the ones relevant to you -- Win32 and Win64.

Comment: The linked website contains “It also is known to work on Windows in both 32-bit and 64-bit mode.”.